# bulk save mapinfo tab files with new projection

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

Is there a way to builk convert mapinfo files to a new projection (and output in the same mapinfo format) without using the mapinfo sdk?

I did look into ogr2ogr but I couldn't get it to work even when I added the to/from epsgs that I needed to the csv files

I need to convert from EGSP 28356 -> EPSG 3857

Comment: When you tried using ogr2ogr in what way did it not work? Did it export the files but not change the projection? Did it just fail completely?

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" {outfile} -t_srs EPSG:3857 {in file}
```